# Finding the surface integral of a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

How many cubic metres of fluid cross the upper hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, $z\ge0$ per second if the velocity of the flow is $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}$ metres per second.

So I have parametrised the hemisphere:

$$\mathbf{r}(\theta, \phi) = (\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}, \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}, \cos{\theta})$$ where $0\le\theta\le \pi/2$, $0\le\phi\le2\pi$. Now I want to find $$\int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{dS}$$

Now I also know $\mathbf{dS}=r^{2}\sin{\theta}{\rm d}\theta{\rm d}\phi \mathbf{\hat{r}}$. How do I continue?

Comment: You need a density function for the fluid, do you not?

Comment: I have modified to fix some things

Comment: The last coordinate should be $\cos(\theta)$. Moreover, shouldn't that be a double integral? And shouldn't the integrand be $(u\cdot n)dS$, where $n$ is a unit normal vector?

Comment: Yes for the cos however I'm not sure about the second bit, how would you answer this question then?

Comment: We want to find the flux of $u$ through the upper hemisphere given. Your parameterization of the surface is correct. But the formula isn't. That's a double integral. I suggest you look up "Surface integral of a vector field". There are many tutorials.

Comment: @Ahmed There is absolutely no need to signify a surface integral by writing two integral signs, only when you are switching to interated integrals by Fubini's theorem. Which in his OP, it didn't happen yet. The surface normal can also be baked into the area element, so those notations are not incorrect.

On first glance, the area element is incorrect, however, since $d\mathbf{S}=r^2\sin\theta\ d\theta d\phi \mathbf{\hat{r}}$.

Comment: @Ahmed What formula are you saying isn't correct? The surface element looks right to me for the surface in the problem statement.

Comment: Also this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the inner product of $\hat u$ with the unit normal. Use

$$\begin{align}
\hat x\cdot \hat r&=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\\\
\hat y\cdot \hat r&=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\\\
\hat z\cdot \hat r&=\cos(\theta)
\end{align}$$

along with $u_y=x=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$ and $u_z=z=\cos(\theta)$ on the unit circle.

Then, proceed to integrate three terms

$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi \tag 1\\\\
&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi \tag 2\\\\
&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\,\cos(\theta)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi \tag 3
\end{align}$$

All three integrals should be straightforward to evaluate.  The first two integrate to zero since the integrals from $0$ to $2\pi$, with respect to $\phi$, of $\cos\phi$ and $\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)$ are obviously zero.